# Applescript - Repeat until static text is not equal to value

Tags: text, static, repeat

I literally only started using Applescript today trying to write macros for an audio program I use so I really don't know a lot and am stumbling through this.

All I need to do is monitor when a certain window is open within the software and then most importantly, when it closes.

When I export a file from my software, a window comes up [image of window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDItG.png) The window has no identifier other than the static text "Bouncing..." In the screenshot there is a cancel button, but this doesn't apply to every instance of the window (depends on what options are selected) so it's the only thing I have to work with.

So far I have this:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Pro Tools" to set myvalue to value of every static text of front window
    repeat with i from 1 to count of myvalue
        if (item i of myvalue = "Bouncing...") then repeat
        end repeat
        
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell
```

Testing this with a popup instead of the repeat stating it has found the static text works. So I'm halfway there.

All I need to do is to repeat this entire process over and over until the window disappears. Obviously when "myvalue" is "Bouncing..." I need to go back to the start, collect the static text values from the window again and then only exit the loop when the static text value of "Bouncing..." doesn't exist.

Currently it seems to exit the loop before the window has closed

Thanks for any help given here, I've spent hours on this and I'm just not knowledgeable enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Found another way around it. It seems it does default to "window 1":

```
try
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat while (value of first static text of window 1 of application process "Pro Tools" = "Bouncing...")
            delay 1
        end repeat

    end tell
end try
```